# Fingerprint Manager or Biometrics for Android M and above

Tags: android, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api

I want to know which one is better to use, Fingerprint Manager or new Biometrics introduced in Android pie 9.

I have created a chat app, and I came across this feature called *Fingerprint Manager*.

While I researched on it looking Android documentation, I found that they have introduced new *Biometrics* for Android 9 pie.

My project's minimum SDK version is 23 (android M) and build SDK version is 28 (android Pie).

I want this 'fingerprint feature' to work in Android versions between 6 (M) and 9 (Pie).

So should I use *Biometrics* or *Fingerprint Manager*?

If I use Biometrics, will it work in previous versions, too? If yes, then how to code with this new feature?

Comment: I think this will be helpful https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0

Comment: @MahrousMansour I can user <code>Fingerprint Manager</code> for marshmallow, but for pie, it states to use <code>Biometrics</code>, which one will be safer to use?

Comment: also check this https://proandroiddev.com/5-steps-to-implement-biometric-authentication-in-android-dbeb825aeee8

Comment: @MahrousMansour the link worked !! thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I understood this to be true:

The true answer is to be completely effective, you will use both Fingerprint manager and the new BiometricPrompt.

Beginning at API level 23 the fingerprint was effectively the only "biometric" available. As devices were increasingly making sensors available to users, Android released the biometricPrompt class to account for as many biometrics as possible. The goal here is to allow- fingerprint, face recognition, voice recognition etc. All of these would be too much for the single minded FingerprintManager. So, as of API28 BiometricPrompt is available.

If you use the FingerprintManager you will need to put quite a bit more work to have a good UI and the functionality. When you use the BiometricPrompt, much of the functionality is built into the BiometricPrompt.builder.

The builder will work on older versions than API 28, but from API 23-27 You may like the UX better by building your own UI.

@engmms posted a very helpful Medium article on building biometrics for both versions of android.

However, further research and use permit me to edit and update this answer:
The Androidx library for biometrics is the only thing you will need to implement a Biometric prompt into your application. For the library(not the hardware) add:

```
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1"
```

This Androidx library has the tools to consolidate all of the biometric capabilities within an android device from Marshmallow to current. You can easily use the callbacks to check for hardware presence, check for hardware availability and check for biometric enrollment then call .canAuthenticate. Additionally the library has all 3 necessary callbacks for authentication...onAuthenticationError, onAuthenticationFailed and onAuthenticationSuccess.

The Androidx BiometricPrompt also has logic to determine not only if a biometric is enrolled but will query the device as to which biometric is enrolled. This lets the library use finger, face, and iris recognition. The current Google phone Pixel 4 does not have a fingerprint scanner, but will recognize both face and iris for authentication through the Androidx library.